# Why is the result of the code is undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
function fun(x){
   x++;
   if(x==2){
      fun(x);
   }else {
      return x;
   }
 }
alert(fun(1));
```

It alert "undefined".
  but if I write it this way:

```
function fun(x){
  x++;
  if(x==2){
     fun(x);
  }else {
    alert(x);
  }

}
fun(1);
```

it will alert 3.

Why it alert "undefined" not 3 in the first situation ? confused about this...

Comment: You need to `return fun(x);`.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this:

```
function fun(x){
   x++;
   if(x==2){
      return fun(x);
   } else {
      return x;
   }
}
alert(fun(1)); //3
```

Otherwise you are not returning any value from the function when `x == 2`

Comment: The question was "why" and not "how do I fix this". An explanation would help.

Answer (score 2):

In your if statement, in the case `x == 2` you are missing a return statement.

This makes that `fun` return undefined.

Modifying it to this should do the trick:

```
function fun(x){
   x++;
   if(x==2){
      return fun(x);
   }else {
      return x;
   }
 }
alert(fun(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Chrome's console and run both the codes one by one, you will find that in both the cases 'undefined' is returned. The only difference is that in one case you are alerting a function and in other case you are alerting an actual value.

In first case undefined is shown because the alert will display the final value returned from the function. In this case you are not returning anything from the function because the return is only in else part. Thus an undefined is returned.

In second case also the same thing is happening. It's because you have alert in the else part the final value is getting displayed in the alert.

Answer (score 0):

If you try following in google chrome developer console -

First paste -

```
function fun(x){
  x++;
  if(x==2){
     fun(x);
  }else {
    alert(x);
  }
}
```

Press enter which will declare function. Then call fun(1). You will still get undefind. This is happened because it is recursive call and in callstack maintain execution sequence. From recusive function call value get return but as there is no return keyword used while calling function recursively it is giving undefind value.

I think callstack played role over here which is causing undefind value because of no return keyword.

Please share your views if I am wrong somewhere.